# a blank white space after hiding admob interstitial ad?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode5, admob

i'm getting about 50px of blank white space at the bottom of the screen after clicking on the hide button on interstitial ad, I'm not able to detect what is causing this
this is the code I'm using to request and view interstitial ads, any ideas on how to solve it ?

```
    - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView*)theWebView
{
    interstitial_ = [[GADInterstitial alloc] init];
    interstitial_.adUnitID = @"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
    interstitial_.delegate = self;
    GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
    request.testDevices = @[                         
                            GAD_SIMULATOR_ID,
                            ];

    [interstitial_ loadRequest:request];
    return [super webViewDidFinishLoad:theWebView];
}


- (void)interstitialDidReceiveAd:(GADBannerView *)adView {
    [interstitial_ presentFromRootViewController:self];
}
```